# Has this Facebook channel changed its username or is it a new page?

Tags: facebook

I have a FB channel in my db that stores the FB ID of the page. Normally when a page changes its username, like going from `sportstadtduesseldorf` to `dsports.sportstadtduesseldorf`, the ID will still the same. I check this by comparing my old id in our db to the one that is found on a website like https://commentpicker.com/find-facebook-id.php. If there is an ID mismatch, I assume that this username is in face a new FB page. This has worked in the past.

However now when a facebook seemingly changes a username, I get an entirely new ID. I want to say that this new FB username is an entirely new page based on my previous methodology but I am unsure. On the new page, I searched the DOM for this old ID and still found it under "ID" and "associated_id", yet when i search the new page on commentpicker.com, i get a new id instead.

My question is; What is going on here in the case of this channel? Is it a new channel or is it the old one with a username change?

**See this example**:

Channel: Sportstadt Düsseldorf

- Old Facebook ID: 120290967983608
- Old Facebook URL (which shouldnt exist anymore): https://www.facebook.com/sportstadtduesseldorf

---

- New Facebook ID found: 100064441939407
- New Facebook URL of same(?) channel: https://www.facebook.com/dsports.sportstadtduesseldorf

Comment: Facebook pages can get merged, when two pages for the same subject/entity exist.

Comment: What's weird though is that `https://www.facebook.com/126637760705884` - what you say was the old ID - redirects to `https://www.facebook.com/enbasketsschwelm/`, which appears to be something completely different, and not at all associated with the topic of the new or old sportstadtduesseldorf page.

Comment: Sorry but it seemed i used the wrong ID which makes sense why you would be redirected. The actual old id  in our system is `120290967983608`, but`https://www.facebook.com/120290967983608` redirects to the new page `https://www.facebook.com/dsports.sportstadtduesseldorf`. So the old id seems valid but maybe isn't the main id

Comment: Likely a case of two pages that got merged then.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I assume then that my old id should remain valid.